# Unity3D - How do I create a loading bar for my object pooling pre-instantiating?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I used the SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync() AsyncOperation to create a loading bar for my scene. The problem is, after the loading bar reaches 100%, it stops there (I'm 99% sure it is doing the object pool's pre-instantiation that is currently in the Awake() method) for a few seconds, then loads the scene. How can I modify the loading bar so that it accounts for the time of the object pool instantiation?

```
public class LevelLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
public static LevelLoader instance;
public GameObject screen;
public Slider slider;
public TextMeshProUGUI progressText;
private float oldProgress = 0f;

private void Awake()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    DontDestroyOnLoad(screen.transform.parent.gameObject);

    instance = this;
    screen.SetActive(false);
}

public void LoadLevel(int sceneIndex)
{
    StartCoroutine(LoadAsync(sceneIndex));
}

IEnumerator LoadAsync(int sceneIndex)
{
    AsyncOperation op = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneIndex);
    screen.SetActive(true);
    while (!op.isDone)
    {
        System.Random rand = new System.Random();
        float progress = Mathf.Lerp(oldProgress, Mathf.Clamp01(op.progress / .9f), rand.Next()); 
        // for smoothness (doesn't actually work i think)

        slider.value = progress;
        progressText.text = (progress * 100f).ToString("f0") + "%";
        oldProgress = progress;

        yield return null;
    }
    screen.SetActive(false);
}
```

}

Comment: Alternative: use a progress ring aka indeterminate progress bar, print what is being loaded on screen. By the way why 0.9 but no scene activation https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AsyncOperation-allowSceneActivation.html ?

Comment: @Aybe I am pretty sure it defaults to true

Comment: Where is the script for the pool initialization? If you know before how much objects will be initialized maybe you could use a list and let the progressbar check it .. however I guess you won't be able to 100% predict how long this takes .. so I would go with letting the progress actually load 90%(loadSceneAsync) and use the last 10% for Initializing the objects (one by one e.g. in a second routine or in the same instead of all at once in `Awake`)

Comment: @derHugo Yes, I know how many objects will be instantiated. That might work

Comment: Depends on what you expect to take longer. You could also make it e.g. 40% for loadScene and than 60% for the pool :)

Comment: I still don't really understand that `Lerp` thing though .. why choosing a random value?

Comment: For a "random" amount of smoothness? xD